# Shannon-Fano coding in Wolfram

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to make a function that codes a string of text using the Shannon-Fano method. I get characters using the `CharacterCounts` function, and I want to make a Grid with individual characters in the first line, and the probability of them in the second line.

How do I separate the characters and their counts from the `CharacterCounts` function output? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cc = CharacterCounts["right said Fred"]
```

> ```
> <|"d" -> 2, " " -> 2, "i" -> 2, "r" -> 2, "e" -> 1, "F" -> 1, 
>  "a" -> 1, "s" -> 1, "t" -> 1, "h" -> 1, "g" -> 1|>
> ```

You can use the functions [`Keys`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Keys.html) and [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
characters = Keys @ cc
```

> ```
> {"d", " ", "i", "r", "e", "F", "a", "s", "t", "h", "g"}
> ```

```
counts = Values @ cc
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

Alternatively, you can get both in a single step using [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html):

```
{characters, counts} = Through[{Keys, Values}@cc]
```

> ```
>  {{"d", " ", "i", "r", "e", "F", "a", "s", "t", "h", "g"},
>    {2, 2, 2, 2,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
Grid[Join[List /@ {"characters", "counts", "frequency"}, 
   {characters, counts, Normalize[counts, Total]}, 2],
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Drobdien, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Just a quick question, what is the purpose of the "2" there?

Comment: @Drobdien, it specifies the `Level` at which objects from `{{"characters"},{ "counts"}, {"frequency"}}` and  `{characters, counts, Normalize[counts, Total]}` should be joined. The default level is `1`.  Compare `Join[{{a}, {b}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 2]` with `Join[{{a}, {b}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 1]` to see the effect of the level specification.